# How to edit Pixelsense application nowadays?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, pixelsense

I developed a PixelSense ([formerly Surface](https://web.archive.org/web/20170710062827/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692162(v=surface.10).aspx), before the tablet even exists) application, back in 2014.

Now I'm asked to make this evolve. But the only SDK relevant I found is [the very same](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26716) I used when I developed it from scratch.

THis SDK **requires Visual Studio 2010** as a mandatory prerequisite. This version seems not even orderable anymore.... I tried with last Visual Studio version, the SDK refuses to install. It's frozen on 2010 one.

SO how can I build a development environment for editing my application?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can still download old version of visual studio (including 2010) from msdn.
https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202010